# Pythonic way to inherit attribute values between classes

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to pass attribute values to derived classes for data managing purpose. Intuitively the code should behave like:

```
class Cls1(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1

class Cls2(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute_2=2):
        self.attribute_2 = attribute_2


cls1 = Cls1(1)
cls2 = Cls2(cls1)
cls2.<tab>

## ideal output should be:
cls2.attribute_1  # this should give whatever value I set in cls1
cls2.attribute_2  # this should give default value 2
```

I know ,in python, class generally inherits method but not attribute values. it seems `suepr().__init__()` or customized `metaclass` can do similar job, but not exactly the way I describe.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do it, like Python philosophy "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Thanks!

Comment: `Cls2` isn't derived from `Cls1`. Either you've specified the wrong parent, or you need to brush up on the relevant terminology and concepts.

Comment: In what way does calling `super().__init__` not work (assuming you make `Cls2` inherit from `Cls1`)?

Comment: Just to clarify, everything you put on the `__init__` method is concerned with instances, not classes. Do you want to instantiate a class based on some instance from another class? If so, this question is probably a dupe.

Comment: yes, I wrongly assigned parent in my example @user2357112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not really inheritance, more like composition (one object wrapped in another). One way you could go about this is to have a method that catches all undefined attribute requests (`__getattr__`), and forwards them to your wrapped object.

```
class Cls1(object):
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1

class Cls2(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.wrapped_obj = obj 
        self.attribute_2 = 2

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        # get in here only when attribute requested is not defined.
        # for Cls2. let's try to get it from our wrapped Cls1 
        # object instead.
        return getattr(self.wrapped_obj, name)


cls1 = Cls1(1)
cls2 = Cls2(cls1)

## ideal output should be:
print cls2.attribute_1  # outputs 1
print cls2.attribute_2  # outputs 2
```

**EDIT:** Clarification of inheritance vs composition:

Inheritance works nicely when you want to inherit code or behaviour from another class, but not internal state (data). It seems that you want to have two separate objects  representing different data, and merge them together.

For this problem you will most likely need composition - not inheritance, because you will still have two neatly separate objects representing the data.

Comment: Thanks! I think I really confused myself with inheritance and composition. Now everything is clear now :)